# Create New IIS 6 Web Site

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have been given a w2k3 server today that is running IIS 6. This is my first time using IIS 6 (I've used 7.x plenty of times) and I cannot find the option to create a new web site, only a new FTP site as seen in the picture below:

[image]

The only help I can find via Google is using the assumption that the Web Sites folder is visible. I suppose that I may have been using all of the wrong search terms, but I can't find a thing to help me with this problem. Clearly, this folder should be visible but it isn't and I don't know where to begin with this one.

How can I add web sites in IIS 6 with this happening to me?

Starting to think that I may have to reinstall IIS 6, but I would like some input before I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that IIS does more than just web sites. So you have IIS running but you may not have the web publishing side of things installed - I think you just have the snap-in for IIS and FTP running. I would check with your Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs > Windows Components > IIS and then click details and make sure that World Wide Web Service is an option you've chosen.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see the "Default Website" folder then you need to go into ...

(Trots off to look in an IIS6 VM)

Control Panel->Add remove programs->Windows Components_>Internet information services

and make sure:

common files
internet information services snapin
world wide web service (and it's sub options)

Are all ticked.

Restart MMC, and you should see it appear...